# Best way to compare two date(data is string type) in linq c#

Tags: c#, linq, date, datetime

I want to compare two date(data is string type) in linq c# as code below.

```
var checkStoreClose = (from s in database.STORE
    where s.StoreClose_DT < txt_inputDateFromUser
    select s);
// s.StoreClose_DT is string "08-Sep-2017"
// txt_inputDateFromUser is string "09-Sep-2017"
```

I think I should do step is as followings:

1. Convert string from dd-MM-yyyy to string MM/dd/yyyy ("8-Sep-2017" to "09/08/2017" and "9-Sep-2017" to "09/09/2017")
2. Convert string from MM/dd/yyyy to date ("09/08/2017" to 09/08/2017 and "09/09/2017" to 09/09/2017)
3. I can compare date.

Could you suggest me, please?

Comment: Can you talk us through why `StoreClose_DT` is a string in the database and not a `datetime` or the like?

Comment: Comparing `DateTime` values with their _textual_ representations (aka `string`) is _almost_ always a bad idea. If they are strings, parse them to DateTime (with proper format if needed) and compare them with `<` or `>` operators.

Comment: @mjwills, I'm not sure because the system/database were developed before I join them and currently no one know the reason. However, I think the filed should be datetime type as you mentioned.

Comment: @SonerGönül, I think so.

Comment: `and currently no one know the reason.` You need to fix it. Storing dates as strings (especially in US date format) will make (performant) database based searching nigh impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTime dtBusinessDate;
DateTime dtStoreClosedDate;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(txt_inputDateFromUser.Value, "d-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dtBusinessDate) && DateTime.TryParseExact(getStoreCloseDT, "d-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dtStoreClosedDate))
{
    if (dtBusinessDate > dtStoreClosedDate)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the date conversion happens client side.

```
var inputDate = DateTime.Parse(txt_inputDateFromUser);
var checkStoreClose = (from s in database.STORE
    where DateTime.Parse(s.StoreClose_DT) < inputDate
    select s);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is OK. However I updated to use DateTime.TryParseExact because s.StoreClose_DT is blank sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var checkStoreClose = (from s in database.STORE
where DateTime.Parse(s.StoreClose_DT) < DateTime.Parse(txt_inputDateFromUser)
select s);
```

Comment: I think this is a terrific answer.  Just a small suggestion - perhaps include the ToList() method after database.STORE   eg
var checkStoreClose = (from s in database.STORE.ToList() where ...

This will ensure you don't get that error about SQL not being able to evaluate a store expression - it just means the DateTime.Parse functions will be able to execute happily in C# rather than have SQL complain about not being able to evaluate it.